ADF Snowflake Connector - Key pair authentication - [Snowflake] adbc.snowflake.sql.client_option.jwt_private_key_pkcs8_password is not configured
I have created a private encrypted key pair to connect ADF to Snowflake. The private key is in Azure key vault secret. When I am trying to test the connection with the key pair using Linked Service, it throws the below error.

The basic jdbc authentication with basic username and password works fine. The odbc authentication with key-pair is also successful. So, the issue is definitely not with the private key in keyvault.
I have followed all the steps from this issue as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1659093/adf-snowflake-connector-key-pair-authentication-fa
Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. TIA

The error message seems to be implying that the private key is passphrase encrypted and you have not provided the passphrase. See the article you linked to for how to include the privateKeyPassphrase.

Hi Dave, I have tried giving the passphrase by entering manually in the UI as well as retrieving from the key vault. It gives a different error now. "Test connection operation failed.
Failed to open the database connection.
[Snowflake] Post "https://tyqzpod-tdetest.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?databaseName=WSIC_TEST&requestId=917b75b3-cb81-47b4-55b1-0325829bbeaa&request_guid=fdd4e2be-57cc-4425-6d12-b50b2ad4fc6e&warehouse=WSIC_ADF_WH": EOF"
